# Doing a Load More Ajax in Silverstripe 4 Blog module

Tags: php, silverstripe-4

Currently I am using SS4 Blog module.
We have used a paginated style of blog.

And now we need a load more ajax for more content.

Any idea on how to do this in SS4?

I am searching for an example of this but the community was not able to give me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear, I will try to answer it in the way I think will make sense.

Pagination: This view is like a book were you actually have to flip through each "Page". If you are on Page 2, you won't see what's on Page 1.

LoadMore: You start on Page 1 then you append results of Page 2 to the View where Page 1 is. This way you can view Page 1 and Page 2 on the same Page creating a stack of pages.

For LoadMore which you asked.
You need a js variable `var currentPage = 1;` to hold the current page to be loaded from the server. Each time you request data you will need to provide the current page you are on. Logically something like this

1. You render your page with Page1 loaded; currentPage = 1;
2. OnClickingLoadMore button; currentPage++;
3. Send the request via ajax. `var url = 'server.com/posts/pull?page='+currentPage;`
4. Append returned data on the current view.

PostsController.php

add the method name to the allowed-action

`private static $allowed_actions = [
    'pull',
 ];`

Create a method called "pull" with the code below in it.

`$oListings = BlogPost::get();
$oList = new PaginatedList( $oListings, $this->request );
$oList->setPageLength( $limit );
$oList->setCurrentPage( $page );`

Lastly your routes.yml (simplified)

`SilverStripe\Control\Director:
  rules:
    'posts//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'PostsController'`

Lastly using jQuery you can APPEND  [http://api.jquery.com/append/] to add more content to your page.

Hope this helps